# In Bash how would you print/use a backslash followed by a pipe?

Tags: bash, tr

If I have a string that is: `get schwifty` and I want to end up with `get\|schwifty`, the first thing I would attempt is:

```
echo "get schwifty" | tr ' ' "\|"
```

this fails however and only returns the pipe. If I attempt to use multiple backslashes the opposite happens, and I only get the backslash and not the pipe.

How can I end up with `get\|schwifty`?

Comment: Use something other than `tr`.

Comment: do you have any suggestions?

Comment: why aren't you trying strong quotes?  `echo "get schwifty" | tr ' ' '\|'`

Comment: @SaintHax `echo "get schwifty" | tr ' ' '\|'` will still just replace spaces with pipes because `tr` uses backslash as an escape character.

Answer (score 6):

[`tr`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tr) can only be used to replace one character with another (or delete characters from the input).

`tr ' ' "\|"` replaces spaces with pipes because the double quotes cause bash to interpret the backslash as an escape character before invoking invoking `tr` (as `tr ' ' '|'`). Note that backslash is also an escape character for `tr` (see the `tr` man page).

You can use [`sed`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) instead:

```
echo "get schwifty" | sed -e 's/ /\\|/g'
```

Alternatively, you can use a bash [pattern substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```
s="get schwifty"
echo "${s/ /\\|}"
```

Comment: this does not work and is only providing the pipes

Comment: @driedupsharpie Both options work for me (see http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMWnJKYXJFTmtiTlE).

Comment: @driedupsharpie, Phil's suggestions work for me, too -- just as I would expect.

Comment: echo "get schifty" | sed -e 's/ /\\\|/g'
He missed an escape character

Comment: Oh sorry, I always forget this difference between single and double quotes.

Comment: @LittleNooby there is no missing escape character. The expression parameter is enclosed by [single quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Single-Quotes), so the shell passes its contents on to `sed` unaltered.